# poll tag causing conflict

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Below is the xhtml body.

```
        <h:outputText value="#{notificationBean.strMessg}" id="outText" escape="false" styleClass="msgCls"/>
        <p:poll interval="20"  listener="#{notificationBean.browerNotified}" update="outText"  id="notificationPoll" >
        </p:poll>
        <audio id="audio1" src="./images/new_notification.wav"  preload="auto"></audio>


</h:body>
```

I have included this xhtml file in another xhtml named "test.xhtml".
My Project consists of 4-5 modules.When i call poll tag in test.xhtml other ajax requests failed to call and shows me the partial response error...

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Index: 0, Size: 0]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
Please check the response am getting...

Comment: Please post the full stack trace which you can find in the server logs.

Comment: am not getting any log for this issue.But found some code conflicts due to some other js files.